# HTML How to make a password without changes the tab

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a website using log in password.
I used this kind of html that I got from the Internet, but it goes weird.
Can you fix the html so I can click log in without open the link to other tab?
Thank you

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
          LOG IN
    </title>
    </head>
      <font size=5 style="font-family:Franklin Gothic Book; text-align="center">
          Please log in
    </font>
      <form name="login">
      <font face="Franklin Gothic Book">User name:<input type="text" name="userid"/><br>
          Password  <font color="white">.</font>:<input type="password" name="pswrd"/><br></font>
      <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
      <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
      </form>
    <script language="javascript">
          function check(form)
          {
            if(form.userid.value == "Queen Crown" && form.pswrd.value == "rank1student")
            {
              window.open('one.html')
            }
            else
            {
              alert("Error Password or Username")
            }
          }
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:
`window.open('one.html')`
to
`window.location('one.html')`

And please note that this is really NOT a secure way to password protect sensative stuff. The password and username can be found by anybody that looks in the source code.